# Firestore rules objects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to setup some basic Firestore security rules in my database. I am having some trouble finding the relevant documentation to learn how to do this.

**Currently my document is structured like this:**

```
project(document): {
  createdBy(string): chris@emailaddress.com,
  users(object): {
    { graham@emailaddress.com(object): access: write },
    { paul@emailaddress.com(object): access: read }
  }
}
```

**I'd like to setup my rules so that**:

- Users must be signed in to read, write or delete anything
- If a user is added to a project with 'read' access they can only read the document.
- If a user is setup with write access they can update and read the document but not update the `createdBy` field.
- If a user has created the document they can read, update and delete the document.

**My security rules are setup like this:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{projectId} {
      allow read: if existingData().users[getUser()token.email].access != null && isSignedInAndVerified()
      allow read, update: if existingData().users[getUser()token.email].access != "write" && isSignedInAndVerified()
      allow update, delete: if sameAsEmail(existingData().createdBy) && isSignedInAndVerified()
    }
    //my functions
    function getUser(){
      return request.auth
    }
    function existingData(){
      return resource.data
    }
    function sameAsEmail(resource){
      return resource == request.auth.token.email
    }
    function isSignedInAndVerified() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of syntax use: `getUser().token.email` instead.